# Have to versus need to

Tags: difference, clauses, parts-of-speech, spoken-english, learning

What is difference between I have to ... and I need to ...?

Like sometime we use I have to go for a meeting but sometime use I need to go for a meeting.

Are both correct or wrong or have any difference?

Answer (score 1):

> need to

is usually used to describe a necessity for survival

> have to

is usually used to describe something that is an obligation.

Sometimes they have the same meaning

> We **have to** breath to live.
>   We **need to** breath to live.
>
> I **have to** attend my mother's birthday party.
>   I **need to** attend my mother's birthday party.

both pairs of sentences have the same meaning, and depending on context one might have a stronger meaning or the same meaning of importance. The nuances can only be learned through usage and an understanding of context.

To contrast the two

> I **have to** get petrol for the car, but I don't **need to** right now, I still have a little.